# streaming webcam via rtp protocol

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, rtp

i am trying to stream and receive my webcam feed on two terminal on same laptop.For this purpose I am using the following commands:-

foo.sdp:

```
SDP:
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 55.2.100
m=video 1235 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1
```

Transmitting:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /dev/video0 -r 24 -b 50k -s 858x500 -f mulaw -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:3000> foo.sdp
```

Receiving:

```
ffplay -i foo.sdp
```

While transmission seems to be working fine , but when i am using receiving command I am getting en error :

```
Protocol not on whitelist 'file,crypto'!/0   
foo.sdp: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Answer (score 13):

try add

-protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#Protocol-Options

https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2016-February/030853.html